# Nested Menu in Toolbar using Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

I would like to create Toolbar with sub menu items. It can be done in Xamarin.Android naively but I want to implement such a kind of feature in IOS and UWP too. I am not mentioning expandable list items. It should be similar to sub menu.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t8ho.png)

I have created this in Xamarin.Android using the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:AMCSMobile="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <!-- Route View - Action Bar Menu -->
  <item
    android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_Messages"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_read_light"
    AMCSMobile:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="@string/ScheduleView_ActionButton_Messages" />

  <item
      android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_Tracking"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_location_found_light"
      AMCSMobile:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="@string/RouteView_Button_TrackingOn" />

  <item
      android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_StartBreak"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_pause_light"
      AMCSMobile:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="@string/RouteView_Button_StartBreak" />

  <item
      android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_Complete"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept_light"
      AMCSMobile:showAsAction="ifRoom"
      android:title="@string/RouteView_Button_Complete" />


  <item
    android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_EventSelection"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new_event_light"
    AMCSMobile:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/ScheduleView_ActionButton_Event"
      >
    <menu>
      <item
        android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_Event_RecordRefuelEvent"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh_light"
        android:title="@string/ScheduleView_ActionButton_Event_RecordRefuelEvent" />
      <item
        android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_Event_RecordDisposalEvent"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_discard_light"
        android:title="@string/ScheduleView_ActionButton_Event_RecordDisposalEvent" />
      <item
        android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_Event_RecordMiscEvent"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_help_light"
        android:title="@string/ScheduleView_ActionButton_Event_RecordMiscEvent" />
      <item
        android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_Event_RecordBlockageEvent"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_warning_light"
        android:title="@string/ScheduleView_ActionButton_Event_RecordBlockageEvent" />
    </menu>
  </item>

  <item
      android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_Commute"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_split_light"
      AMCSMobile:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="@string/RouteView_Button_ShowCommute" />

  <item
      android:id="@+id/RouteView_ActionButton_Logout"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_back_light"
      AMCSMobile:showAsAction="never"
      android:title="@string/RouteView_Button_Logout" />

</menu>
```

I want to know whether it is possible to do it in other platforms (IOS and UWP) or not. Kindly let me know your suggestion please.

Comment: An interesting question I am waiting for answers with you.

Comment: 1.UWP:use  MenuFlyoutSubItem Refer to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817507/windows-10-uwp-app-menu-flyout-inside-menu-item  2.iOS: TableView . refer to https://github.com/gkopel/nmoutlineview